# Is it possible to pass url parameter when creating an instance of Backbone Collection object?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

Is it possible to pass url parameter when creating an instance of Collection object? I would like to create an array of collections containing data for all pages.

```
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: MainModel,
    initialize: function (models,options) {
        var self = this;
        self.fetch();   
    }
});

var Collections = {
    news : new Collection({url : "../data/news"}),
    projects : new Collection({url : "../data/projects"}),
    home : new Collection({url : "../data/home"})
};
```

Is that possible like this, or I am doing something terribly wrong? Do I need to create a collection for each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you will want to create a new collection for each type of model

Comment: I guess I know what you mean. You have a page, contains lot of informations like news, projects, etc. You want to manage them as a whole, in a collection array. So if you want to like go to next page, you can just go through the array of collections and fetch

Answer (score 0):

I also find this issue and i get it solved .. Here is the quick answer.

Collection Object

```
 var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        initialize : function(models,options){
            this.model = options.model ,
            this.url = options.url
        }
    });
```

here is how i create my new collection instace

```
var events = new Events([],{ model : modelName , url : 'urlToGo' });
```

Hope you help